# How to take an assest I made and group it together to Appended in another project?

Tags: groups, append

all I am very new to blender. I have been googling but cannot seem to find anything. I made a dumpster for scenes to use in the future. I parented it to an empty, but I cannot figure out how to group it all with all my textures and multiple objects and bring it into another project. I understand you need to do in the new project append > objects (or collections?) but I do not know how to set it up for that. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. As I stated I have looked through google but I must just not be using the proper terms for the info I need.

Best,

Jordan[image]

Comment: You already organize everything inside collections, save the file and you just need to append the collections that you need in a new scene

Comment: Super weird. I have to bring in the wheels and lid separately. I am not sure how I organized it wrong. I guess I can get the whole thing, but just in three passes. Thank you and if you have any info on how I could have goofed this up I would appreciate it!